# Tkinter : Issue with creating keyboard shortcuts

Tags: python, function, tkinter, bind

I'm having problem with making keyboard shortcuts for my program. I couldn't seem to get `root.bind("<Control-Shift-s>",function)` to work, but `root.bind("<Control-s>",function)` works perfectly. Here's the example code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def function():
    print("This is a function")

root.bind("<Control-Shift-s>",function) # Doesn't work
root.bind("<Control-s>",function) # Works perfectly

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
root.bind("<Control-Shift-s>",function) # Doesn't work
```

To one of these:

1. `root.bind("<`<kbd>Control</kbd>`-`<kbd>Shift_L</kbd>`><`<kbd>S</kbd>>`",function)`
2. `root.bind("<`<kbd>Control</kbd>`-`<kbd>Shift_R</kbd>`><`<kbd>S</kbd>`>",function)`
3. `root.bind("<`<kbd>Control</kbd>`-`<kbd>Shift</kbd>`-`<kbd>S</kbd>`>",function)`

([*Reference*](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm))

Comment: Some of the fiddly details of key binding are OS specific.  Hung, which are you using?

Comment: Actually, this is fine as well `<Control-Shift-S>` the S needs to be capital because you are holding shift so you expect a capital S. Also `function` needs to take a parameter otherwise you get an error.

Comment: every time my program is opened though the binding gets run immediately